# Inline Editing cannot update Data in custom controller Apex

Tags: controller, salesforce, inline-editing

I need to update data from inline Editing in apex using Custom Controller and Everything seems to be fine but cannot update the value List provided in the PageBlockTable.The page is supposed to fetch 10 records at a time PleaseHelp ...

```
        <!--Visual Forcepage-->
        <apex:page controller="NativeAccountsClass">
        <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts with Mailing Address set to India" id="accounts_list" mode="inlineEdit" >

            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="saveButton"/>
            <!--
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancelButton"/>
            -->    
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! ListOfAccounts }"  var="ac">
             <!-- <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" showOnEdit="saveButton"/> -->

                <apex:column value="{! ac.Name }">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!sortByName}" reRender="accounts_list">Name
                        </apex:commandLink>

                    </apex:facet>
                  <!--     -->
                </apex:column>
                  <!-- 
                     <apex:column>
                    <apex:facet name='header'>
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!sortByParent}" reRender="accounts_list">Parent
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
                -->
                <apex:column value="{! ac.Rating}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{! sortByRating}" reRender="accounts_list">Rating
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column value="{! ac.NumberOfEmployees}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{! sortByNoOfEmployees}" reRender="accounts_list">Total Employees
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column value="{! ac.Website}">
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink action="{! sortByWebsite}">Website
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{! ac.BillingCountry }" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <!-- Pagination -->
        <table style="width: 100%"><tr>
            <td>
                Page: <apex:outputText value=" {!pageNumber} of {! CEILING(resultSize/pageSize)}" />
            </td>            
            <td align="center">
                <!-- Previous page -->
                <!-- active -->
                <apex:commandLink action="{! Previous }" value="« Previous" 
                                  rendered="{! HasPrevious }" reRender="accounts_list"  />
                <!-- inactive (no earlier pages) -->
                <apex:outputText style="color: #ccc;" value="« Previous"
                                 rendered="{! NOT(HasPrevious) }"/>  

                &nbsp;&nbsp;  

                <!-- Next page -->
                <!-- active -->
                <apex:commandLink action="{! Next }" value="Next »" 
                                  rendered="{! HasNext }" reRender="accounts_list"/> 
                <!-- inactive (no more pages) -->
                <apex:outputText style="color: #ccc;" value="Next »"
                                 rendered="{! NOT(HasNext) }"/> 
            </td>

            <td align="right">
                <!-- Records per page -->
            </td>

            </tr></table>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The Controller :

```
    public class NativeAccountsClass {
    String country='india';
    String sortOrder = 'Name';
    Map<integer,List<Account>> results;
    public List<Account> ListOfAccounts{get;set;}
    public Integer pageSize{get;set;}
    public Integer pageNumber{get;set;}
    public Integer resultSize{get;set;}
    Integer noOfPages;
    List<Account> allRecords;
    List<Account> updatedList;
    Account accountobj;
    public Boolean HasPrevious{get;set;}
    public Boolean HasNext {get;set;}

    public NativeAccountsClass(){
        updatedList = new List<Account>(); 
        HasPrevious = False;
        HasNext = True;
        pageSize=10;
        pageNumber=1;
        String accountQuery = 'Select Name,Rating,NumberOfEmployees,Website,BillingCountry ' +
            'FROM Account ' +
            'WHERE BillingCountry = :country ' +
            'ORDER BY ' + sortOrder + ' ASC';
        allRecords = Database.query(accountQuery);
        resultSize = allRecords.size();

        Integer recForPage;
        Integer page=1,index=0;
        List<Account> tempList = new List<Account>();
        results = new Map<integer,List<Account>>();


        noOfPages =resultSize/pageSize;
        Integer div = Math.mod(resultSize,pageSize);
        if(div>0)
            noOfPages++;
        while(page<=noOfPages){
            recForPage=1;
            System.debug('Pageno = '+ page );
            while(recForPage<=pageSize && Index < resultSize){
                tempList.add(allRecords.get(index));
                recForPage++;
                index++;
            }
            results.put(page,tempList);
            tempList= new List<Account>();
            page++;
        }
        ListOfAccounts = results.get(pageNumber);
    }

    public void getAccounts(){   
        ListOfAccounts = results.get(pageNumber);
    }

    public void save(){
        System.debug(ListOfAccounts);
        update ListOfAccounts;
        getAccounts();
    }
    public void sortByParent(){
        this.sortOrder = 'Parent';
        allRecords=NULL;
        getAccounts();
    }
    public void sortByRating(){
        this.sortOrder = 'Rating';
        allRecords=NULL;
        getAccounts();
    }
    public void sortByNoOfEmployees(){
        this.sortOrder = 'NumberOfEmployees';
        allRecords=NULL;
        getAccounts();
    }
    public void sortByWebsite(){
        this.sortOrder = 'Website';
        allRecords=NULL;
        getAccounts();
    }
    public void sortByName(){
        this.sortOrder='Name';
        allRecords = NULL;
        getAccounts();
    }
    /*
public integer getpageSize(){
return this.pageSize;
}
public integer getpageNumber(){
return this.pageNumber;
}
public Integer getresultSize(){
return resultSize;
}
*/
    public void Previous(){
        HasPrevious =True;
        HasNext = True;
        pageNumber--;
        if(pageNumber == 1)
            HasPrevious =false;
        getAccounts();
    }
    public void Next(){
        HasPrevious = True;
        pageNumber++;
        if(pageNumber == noOfPages)
            HasNext = False;
        else
            HasNext = True;
        getAccounts();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `<apex:column>` tag because it contains the latest element from the list instead use `<apex:outputfield>` which will keep the fields of the records independent.
The problem could be that `<apex:column>` only contains the last element from the list and hence only that element will be updated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use CommandLink Instead Of commandButton for the !save action